# Calculation of coefficients of this simple sequence of polynomials

Tags: polynomials

For $k \in \mathbb N$ we have polynomial $n(n+1) \cdots (n+k-1)$.

I would like to know how to determine the value of coefficients of this sequence of polynomials. Is there any formula for this coefficients?

Comment: Do you already know about binomial expansion, Pascal's triangle, factorials, choices, and permutations?

Comment: @Wildcard Only *choices* sounds unfamiliar. Other terms are known to me and I know something about them.

Comment: If you are talking about a polynomial in terms of $n$, look at [stirling numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind).

Comment: Choices as in, N choose k.  Or, 52 choose 5 = how many different poker hands are there.

Comment: @Wildcard Oh, I call them binomial coeffcients. I know about them.

Comment: @JMoravitz Where can I find everything about them?

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin A good first place to read about stirling numbers of the first kind is on the wikipedia page that I linked in my first comment.  Another place you can go to look if that wasn't sufficient is [stanley's enumerative combinatorics](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/).  It appears specifically on pages 32 and 33 of [volume1version2](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/ec1.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$P_{k}(n) = n(n+1) \cdots (n+k-1)$$
then
\begin{align}
P_{1}(n) &= n \\
P_{2}(n) &= n^2 + n \\
P_{3}(n) &= n^{3} + 3 \, n^{2} + 2 \, n 
\end{align}
and so on. One can easily identify the coefficients with those of the unsigned Stirling numbers of the first kind. These coefficients can be found in table form from Oeis in sequence A094638.

Comment: $P_3(n) = n^3+3n^2+2n$

Comment: Also, these are the unsigned stirling numbers of the *first* kind

Comment: Typing before thinking causes errors.